# If $G$ is a compact Lie group acting as bundle automorphisms of $L$ then why can we choose the metric on $M$ and the connection to be $G$-invariant.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact Manifold and $L\to M$ be a Hermitian Line bundle compatible with connection $\nabla$ and $G$ is a compact Lie group acting as bundle automorphisms of $L$ then why can we choose the metric on $M$ and the connection to be $G$-invariant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a general principle: whenever a compact group acts on a convex set by affine transformations, the 'center of gravity' of an orbit is a fixed point (see below).

For example, if a compact Lie group $G$ acts smoothly on a differential manifold $M$, then it  acts on the set of riemannian metrics on it, which is a convex subset of the space of all tensors of rank 2 on $M$. Hence there is a $G$-invariant  metric on $M$.

If one has some vector bundle $E$ on $M$ and the action of $G$ lifts to an action on $E$, then $G$ acts on the space of connections on $E$, which is an affine space (modeled on the space of 1-forms on $M$ with values in $End(E)$), hence $E$ admits a $G$-invariant connection. If you want the connection to preserve some given hermitian structure on $E$, then you need the $G$ action to preserve it to begin with. Again, you can always find a $G$-invariant hermitian metric on $E$ (the set of hermitian metrics on $E$ is a convex subset of... etc).

As for the general principle, the proof is by  averaging: if $G$ acts in $A$ by affine transformations and $a\in A$, then the center of gravity of the orbit $G\cdot a$ is defined as  $\langle a\rangle:=\int_G (g\cdot a) dg$, where $dg$ is a left-invariant probability measure on $G$ (also called Haar measure). Its existence is assured for compact groups. Using the left-invariance of $dg$ you can show that $\langle a\rangle$ is a fixed point of $G$ (you need some minimal regularity assumptions on the action, eg continuous).